# If I have PHP fetched/echoed meta descriptions and keywords, will this negatively affect my SEO potential?

Tags: php, seo, text-files, keyword

I have seen posts which indicate that database linked keywords and descriptions are not viable for SEO purposes.

I have also read posts which say that output php has the same SEO potential as html.

I have PHP echoed meta keywords and a meta description fetched from an editable text file in a relative linked folder.

Code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "textSourceFiles/metaDescription.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo "<meta name='description' content='$theData' />";
?>
```

Short question: Is this pointless? (the keywords and description output is perfect, by the way)

Many thanks

/Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with doing this t all. It appears as if it was in the HTML doc. What you don't want to do is use JavaScript to pop them out as the page has already loaded. As long as it is done on the server end and not after the page has been parsed, search engines won't have any clue or care about how it was done.

On that note, why read the file and then echo it out? Why not just include it in the right place?

Comment: I am building a small and simple "CMS" for a series of small & similar pages where administers can change the description and keywords in accordance with the content. And when I say "CMS" try not to think I actually know what I am talking about.  It is an over-glorified HTML page with forms that then post the values to various text and XML files... which then are sucked up (just to be technical) by the respective site/page.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what sort of *posts* you are reading, but that is completely wrong.  It doesn't matter how the keywords and/or description get added to the rendered output.

The output of PHP is almost always HTML (of course there are exceptions).  Any crawler (google or otherwise) will just see the rendered HTML and it really has no idea of how it was generated.

**EDIT**
An important point is made by @Fluffeh, of Javascript is used, then most likely a crawler will not get the updated DOM elements after the Javascript has actually been run.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen posts which indicate that database linked keywords and
>   descriptions are not viable for SEO purposes.

Anyone who says this should be ignored because it's clear that they don't know what they're talking about.

The only thing that matters is output.

Comment: HAHAHA.....  who to trust!? ;-P